# Sprite physics showing up but not visually showing up in Swift (SpriteKit)

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, sprite, maze

I set up the sprite's physics body, zPosition, color, size, etc., but it won't appear visually. (It has the highest zPosition of my sprites, and YES I did import SpriteKit)

```
let wall = SKSpriteNode()
wall.physicsBody?.velocity = CGVector(dx: 0, dy: 0)
//Takes screen size / width to make each piece one/(value set by "maze" at top) of the screen
let width: CGFloat = (UIScreen.main.bounds.width) / CGFloat(mazeSize)
let height: CGFloat = (UIScreen.main.bounds.height - 134) / CGFloat(mazeSize) //subtract so there's extra room on top+bottom of screen
wall.color = UIColor(ciColor: .black)
wall.isHidden = false
wall.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOf: CGSize(width: width, height: height))
wall.physicsBody?.restitution = 0
wall.physicsBody?.friction = 0
wall.physicsBody?.isDynamic = false
wall.zPosition = 4
//sets up x+y location based on row count and which row this is on
//locations (ONLY positive)
let xLoc: CGFloat = ((UIScreen.main.bounds.width) / CGFloat((mazeSize/2))) * CGFloat(i/mazeSize)
let yLoc: CGFloat = ((UIScreen.main.bounds.height - 134) / CGFloat(mazeSize/2)) * CGFloat(i/mazeSize)
if((i/mazeSize) > (mazeSize/2)){ //if positive on x
    wall.position.x = xLoc
}
else{ //if negative on x
    wall.position.x = -xLoc
}
if(i > ((mazeSize^2)/2)){ //if positive on y
    wall.position.x = yLoc
}
else{ //if negative on y
    wall.position.y = yLoc
}
```

I'm using this to set up walls in a maze (Yes I know the x+y positions are wrong, but they still "appear" clumped in the middle), but only the physics of these nodes show up. Is there a way I can make these black walls appear?

Comment: Don't use the UScreen class to determined the position of a sprite node in a SpriteKit.

Comment: I'll try to keep that in mind while debugging the rest of my code, thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The geometry of the sprite node and the geometry of the physics body don't have to be related, and in this case you've made a rectangular physics body and basically an empty sprite node.  Try something like

```swift
let wall = SKSpriteNode(color: .black, size: CGSize(width: 100, height: 100)
```

or using the `SKSpriteNode(texture:)` initializer.

Comment: Thanks! This worked perfectly (except for the rest of my buggy code), but is there a way to do it while still initializing a sprite like I did? Just wondering for future projects.